# freebase - topic description/articles

Tags: freebase, mql

I'm trying to retrieve the **topic description** for some film ("*/film/film*") and film genres ("*film/film_genre*") **in italian language**.

I think the problem is the same in both cases, so I post the MQL query that I'm trying to run for the film genre description:

---

**Mql query**

```
[{
  "type": "/film/film_genre",
  "name": "Film culto",
  "/common/topic/article": [{
    "id": null
  }]
}]
```

**Response**

```
{
  "result": [{
    "type": "/film/film_genre",
    "name": "Film culto",
    "/common/topic/article": [{
      "id": "/m/01q0d"
    }]
  }]
}
```

---

With the article ID received ("*/m/01q0d*"), I would use the "trans/wrap" service (http://api.freebase.com/api/trans/raw/m/01q0d). However, even though I use the query parameter "lang=it", the article is in English... :(

Any suggestions? I'm going crazy :D

Comment: Be aware the the entire api.freebase.com API was discontinued yesterday - you need to be using the new [Google API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/).

Comment: Even not using the old "trans/wrap" service, the result is the same.
The article that the query returns is in English:
https://www.freebase.com/m/01q0d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freebase contains non-English names, but it doesn't, for the most part, contain descriptions in anything other than English.  You could use the Topic API and get the /common/topic/topic_equivalent_webpage for the Italian Wikipedia to fetch the article/description from there, but that's probably the closest you'll get.

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/01q03

And, as Phil said, the api.freebase.com is going away in a matter of days, so you need to be using the new APIs.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.
I was hoping for a shorter way, but if there is no alternative ... I'll try to retrieve, via MQL, the "equivalent webpages" of the topic and extract the contents from the italian page of Wikipedia.
Thanks